# Need JSRuntime / Blazor to return a value back to Blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor

I have an application that uses custom alert, confirm, and prompt boxes. I have the logic stored in its custom js file. In my blazor app I have a function I call

```
public async Task ShowPromptModBox()
{
    var result = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("showPrompt");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This is called the following javascript function.

```
function showPrompt() {
    cuteAlert({
        type: "question",
        title: "Confirm Title",
        message: "Confirm Message",
        confirmText: "Okay",
        cancelText: "Cancel"
    }).then((e) => {
        if (e == ("Thanks")) {
            return "Yes"
        } else {
            return "No"
        }
    })
}
```

The problem I am facing is that this call is returning a value automatically to result and not waiting if I need to wait for user input. The return value is null. I though that await held execution until the call was finished. Perhaps the javascript function I wrote is returning immediately, and I am missing something for it to wait for user input. Either way, I'm stumped as to how to make javascript here wait for the user to click the Okay button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I think you are just not returning anything. When you return inside `.then` you are returning from the `then` function and not `showPrompt`. This solution assumes `cuteAlert` uses promises and not some just something that looks similar.

```js
async function showPrompt() {
    const response = await cuteAlert({
        type: "question",
        title: "Confirm Title",
        message: "Confirm Message",
        confirmText: "Okay",
        cancelText: "Cancel"
    });
    if (response === "Thanks") {
       return "Yes"
    } else {
       return "No"
    }
}
```